# Autoit Script to start Powershell on remote server using Teamviewer Session

Tags: powershell, autoit, teamviewer

I am trying to automate the access process using teamviewer session. I have to kick Powershell script kept on remote server using autoit script and problem i am facing is autoit not recognizing the remote connection. Below is one i tried.. Running Teamviewer from my local and authenticating the server using TV session ID and password and once i logged in kicking powershell console to execute the script.

```
Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe")
WinWaitActive("TeamViewer")
Sleep(5000)
Send("213322822")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("{ENTER}")
sleep(2000)
WinWaitActive("TeamViewer Authentication")
Send("abcd@123",1)
Send("{ENTER}")
Run("C:\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe")
```

Comment: You just need to run a powershell script remotely?

Comment: What exactly you mean by running PS remotely. Above script is autoit acript which is getting interacted with TeamViewer and connect to server. Once server login gets completed how can i kick powershell on server as we dont have autoit installed on server. Any specific command of Powershell can work here??

Comment: I guess my question is "Why do you need to open powershell this way?" What happens next? What do you want to do with that powershell session on the remote machine?

Comment: Okies.. So with PS i am executing on server to get one screenshot of Teamviewer ID and password from server and send it to my mail ID. Since autoit is not installed on server so i am trying kick screen shot PS on server.